# Where can I reset the highlighting for cErrInParen and cErrInBracket in VIM?

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

While opening the .c file with VIM on Linux, the “{“ and “}” is highlighted as an error where they are okay.

I’d like to reset the highlighting for cErrInParen and cErrInBracket, but don’t know where can I reset it. Thank you.

Comment: Wherever your syntax directory is the highlighting rule will be in c.vim. On linux you'd need to have the change in your local syntax directory, can't remember where that is.The c.vim I have tries to address this error

Comment: I have the same issue. Why does it show as an error in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it work to add the following in `~/.vim/after/syntax/c.vim`:

```
syntax clear cErrInParen
syntax clear cErrInBracket
```

?

Comment: It shows the following message: "E28: No such highlight group name: cErrInParen, E28: No such highlight group name: cErrInBracket"

Comment: It works when I type syntax clear cErrInParen while opening the .c file. But if I add it into the .vimrc or c.vim, it will give me the above error while open any file.

Comment: did you find a solution with your errors? In vimrc I guess it might make sense for most of the other filetype, as these groups must be specific to C